# c# devexpress gridview row collect

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, row

c# devexpress gridview selected row count error 
i want to get row from anouther form(gridcontrol), i tryed form.gridview.selected.row.count but its not working. what can i write for the get this count?  and from other forms of money, i want to print labels to collect this form.
""

```
gridView1.Columns["money"].SummaryItem.SummaryType = DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum;
            gridView1.Columns["money"].SummaryItem.DisplayFormat = "Toplam:{0:n2}";
            gridView1.OptionsView.ShowFooter = true;
```

""
i tryed this code its working but on the gridview but i want to write other form in the label.

Answer (score 1):

form1 have gridView1.

form2 have label2. label2 display Sum from gridView1.

form1 must has form2 as its field or property.

form2 must has method `public void SetSum(money sum)` to set sum for label2.

Every count sum (e.g by click button) call form2.SetSum(sum)

MainForm.cs - Hosts form1 and form2

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private Form1 _form1;

    private Form2 _form2;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _form2 = new Form2();
        _form1 = new Form1(_form2);
    }

    private void btnForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form1.Show(this);
    }

    private void btnForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _form2.Show(this);
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _receivedForm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(Form2 receivedForm) : this()
    {
        _receivedForm = receivedForm;
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _receivedForm.SetSum(txtSum.Text);
    }
}
```

Form2.cs:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetSum(string sum)
    {
        lblSum.Text = sum;
    }
}
```

[image]
Hope this help. :D

Answer (score 0):

ı did with this code now is working. thanks for all answer

```
DataBaseDataContext db = new DataBaseDataContext();
       var sum = (from ord in db.safes select ord.money).Sum();
                lbl_safein.Text = sum.ToString();
```